How to include the file name and the file extension when using MemoryStream in blazor webassembly
Here is my code
getting the file from FileSelectFileInfo
public FileSelectFileInfo selectedFile { get; set; }

then if there is a selected file, i store it in the variable above
private async Task OnSelectHandler(FileSelectEventArgs args)
{
    selectedFile = args.Files[0];
}

this triggers an API endpoint to be executed
private async Task OnSubmit()
{
    try
    {
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await selectedFile.Stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File is empty");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

I'm expecting to pass it to an API endpoint that`s accepting a Stream

Please try this code..
private async Task OnSubmit() {
      try {
        if (selectedFile != null) {
          using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            await selectedFile.Stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            formData.Add(new StreamContent(memoryStream), "file", selectedFile.Name);
    
            using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
              var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/upload", formData);
    
              if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully!");
              } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine("File is empty");
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
      }
    }

